# Setting up some properties for a combobox (scroll, edit, jump)

Tags: forms, excel, vba

There are 3 properties that I want to set for some VBA form comboboxes and I don't know if it's possible.
I don't want to let the combobox editable. Right now if the user types something in it that it submits the form it will send that value... I want to let him choose only from the values I added in the Combobox.
I want to make the list of items in the combobox scroll-able. Right now I'm able to scroll through the list if I use the scroll-bar but I don't know why I can't scroll with the mouse scroll.
And I want to jump to some item if I start typing. Let's say I have the months of the year in one combobox... if I start to type mar I want it to jump to march. I know that for the html forms this properties is by default but I don't know about VBA forms...
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the behaviours you want, some are possible with settings on the Combo, others you will need to code

1. List of Months: Put a list of entries on a (hidden) sheet and name the range. Set `.RowSource` to that range
2. Match as you type: Set properties `.MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryComplete` and `.MatchRequired = True`
3. Reject non list entries: A Combo with these settings will allow you to type an invalid entry, but will reject it with an error message popup when you commit.  If you want to silently reject invalid data as you type, you will need to code it.
4. If you want the selected value returned to a sheet, set `.ControlSource` to a cell address (preferable a named range)
5. By *"...scroll with the mouse scroll..."*  I assume you mean the mouse wheel.  Unfortunatley Forms don't support mouse wheel scroll.  You will have to code it yourself.  There is a Microsoft patch for this at [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-support-for-the-scroll-wheel-to-the-microsoft-visual-basic-for-applications-6-environment-HA010117590.aspx) (not tried it myself yet)

Sample code to silently reject invalid entries

```
Private Sub cmbMonth_Change()
    Static idx As Long
    Dim Match As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    If cmbMonth.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If idx = 0 Then idx = 1
    i = idx
    Match = False
    For i = 0 To cmbMonth.ListCount
        If cmbMonth.List((i + idx - 1) Mod cmbMonth.ListCount) Like cmbMonth.Value & "*" Then
           cmbMonth.ListIndex = (i + idx - 1) Mod cmbMonth.ListCount
           Match = True
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not Match Then
        cmbMonth.Value = Left(cmbMonth.Value, Len(cmbMonth.Value) - 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the propertie MatchEntry of combobox to 1 (fmMatchEntryComplete) and MatchRequired to true for example

```
combobox1.MatchEntry=1
combobox1.MatchRequired=True
```

[]'s